# Computation of completion of a local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-completions

> Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[a,b]/(a^2+b^2+1))$ and consider the closed point $p=(a)$. 
>   I would like to compute the completion of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ w.r.t. to its maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

Since $(\mathcal{O}_{X,p},\mathfrak{m}) $ is a noetherian regular local ring of dimension one with residue field $\mathbb{C}$, so will be $(\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X, \, p},\widehat{\mathfrak m})$ and by Cohen's structure theorem this should yield that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X, \, p}\cong \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ (I copied the argument from [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/191737/132180)).

I tried to write out the explicit isomorphism, but I fail to see how to construct a map $\mathbb{C}[[t]]\to (\mathbb{R}[a,b]/(a^2+b^2+1))_\mathfrak m)/a^n=\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak m^n$ for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: The argument you copied assumes that the ring contains its residue field. How do you show that the completion contains $\mathbb{C}$? Or is there a different argument?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C0S Here it states that it is sufficient for it contain any field

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about this fact in detail, and the reference is certainly nice. I think @jgon's answer below explains the proof in the reference (the part where one needs to use formal smoothness to construct the inclusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Generalizations).

Let $A=\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,p}$, so I can save myself some typing. $\newcommand\mm{\mathfrak{m}}$

Based on the first two cases we generally expect that $i\mapsto b$ (ish) and $t\mapsto a$.

The first step is to find the actual root $u\in A$ of $x^2+1$ which satisfies $u\equiv b\pmod{\mm}$.

We are guaranteed such a thing by Hensel's lemma, but I suspect you'd like a procedure to compute it.

The way Hensel's lemma works is we inductively find solutions to the equation mod $\mm^n$. Here's the first few examples.

$b$ is a solution mod $\mm$, and
$b$ is still a solution mod $\mm^2$.
Now we want to find $b_2\in\mm^2/\mm^3$ with $(b+b_2)^2+1\equiv 0 \pmod{\mm^3}$.
Consider now $$0=(b+b_2)^2+1\equiv b^2+2bb_2+1\pmod{\mm^3}. $$
Rearranging, and using that $2b$ is invertible (since we localized at $(a)$), we get 
$$b_2 = -\frac{b^2+1}{2b}+\mm_3.$$
Then similarly we have $$b_3 = \frac{-(b+b_2)^2}{2b} +\mm^4,$$
$$b_4 = \frac{-(b+b_2+b_3)^2}{2b} + \mm^5,$$
and so on. Ultimately we get $c = b+b_2+b_3+\cdots$, which is a valid element of the completion (since $b_n\in \mm^n/\mm^{n+1}$ for all $n$), and $c^2+1=0$.

This gives us the map $\Bbb{C}\to A$.

Sending $t\to a$, we should get the desired isomorphism $\Bbb{C}[[t]]$ to $A$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of Hensel's lemma. Indeed I wouldn't like the explicit procedure, I was more interested in knowing _how_ I would find such an element. Thanks very much!